# error with function template -- has not been declared

Tags: c++, templates

I am doing some exercises to understand C++ template. My intention is to do a function template that changes behavior in base of template class.

I obtain the following error message:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
test1.h: In function ‘int my::fun(char*, int)’:
test1.h:12:26: error: ‘my::T’ has not been declared
```

The simplified files are the following

------ file test1.h -------

```
#ifndef TEST_1_H
#define TEST_1_H

#include "test2.h"

namespace my
{
  template <typename T = myclass>
  int fun(char* str,int dim)
  {
    return my::T::fun(str,dim);  
  }
}

#endif
```

----- file test2.h -------

```
#ifndef TEST_2_H
#define TEST_2_H

namespace my
{
  struct myclass
  {
    static int fun(char* str,int dim);
  };
}  

#endif
```

------ file test2.cpp --------

```
#include "test2.h"

namespace my
{
  int myclass::fun(char* str,int dim)
  {return 0;}
}
```

----- file main.cpp -------

```
#include "test2.h"
#include "test1.h"

int main()
{}
```

Can you please help me figure out where mistake ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To compile I use new standard:
g++ -std=c++11 test2.cpp main.cpp

Comment: Just remove the my:: before T. Templates arguments do not live in namespaces.

Comment: Hi Coert, 
it works fine.
Thanks very much.
So when I use a template argument never I must qualified the template argument.

Comment: Indeed! You do not need to do that.

Comment: Ok. In other word because the argument template is a place holder for a generic type that will be defined somewhere.
When I use the function template, I can qualify the type for example my::fun<my::myclass>(..,..)
Or I can use qualified default argument for example template <typename T = my::myclass>....
THANKS A LOT, I think to understand

Answer (score 0):

The name `T` is an identifier for a template argument. It dioes not live in any namespace. Argument names or local variables can't be qualified, either. Just remove the `my::`. It seems to be a left-over frim a version of the code using `my::myclass` which wasn't a function template.

With the qualification you are referring to a name at namespace scope:

```
namespace my {
    struct T {};
    template <typename T>
    void f() {
         my::T from_namespace;
         T        from_template_argument;
    }
}
```